# Radix sort algorithm with O(n) worst case

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, radix-sort

Let's say that you are given an integer array `A` of size `n`.  You know in advance that `O(√n)` elements of `A` can be larger than `2020(n)^(5) − 5n`, and the remaining elements of A are in the range `[1, 2020n^5 − 5n]`. It turns out that, in this case, `A` can be sorted in `O(n)` time in the worst case.

I am trying to solve this interesting algorithm question and my intuition is to use radix sort as part of my solution. The part that stumps me is the `O(√n)` runtime, so any pointers in finding such an algorithm would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Separate the in-range elements from the out-of-range elements (O(n)). Radix sort in the in-range elements (base n; this takes six passes for n ≥ 2020 and is O(n)). Insertion sort the out-of-range elements (there are √n of these, hence O(√n²) = O(n)). Merge the two sorted arrays (O(n)).

Comment: how do I ensure that this will run in O(n) time in the worst case? Wouldn't doing radix sort and then insertion sort lead to a slower worst case running algorithm?

Comment: You're only doing insertion sort on O(√n) elements, so the insertion sort only contributes O((√n)^2) = O(n) to the running time.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you have to radix sort the small elements in base n? Any fixed base size results in O(n log n) time.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you that makes so much sense! I think I am able to code this up now!

Comment: Hmm, how do you know it will be 6 passes?

Comment: @Surt the numbers are in [1, n^6] in this case. (The running time for n < 2020 doesn't matter asymptotically.)